# How can I test if a string the last “part” of another string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, indexof

```
var longString = "this string is long but why"
var shortString = "but why"
```

How can i test if shortString is the not only contained in longString but it is actually the last part of the string.

I used `indexOf == 0` to test for the start of the string but not sure how to get the end of it

Comment: `javascript` im assuming?

Comment: Which programming language are you using and what have you tried so far ? Further, this case can be solved with a simple "substring" - why do you want to use regex which is way inferior from performance perspective ?

Comment: sorry yes it is javascript

Answer (score 5):

You don't need regex, if it is javascript you can just do:

```
longString.endsWith(shortString)
```

Comment: `endsWith()` seems to be added with an external library.

Comment: Ignore that comment. This has been added to the ECMAScript 6 specification. Not all javascript implementations may support it yet however. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: Well, for the time being, you can use a polyfill library such as the ones mentioned in [ES6-tools](https://github.com/addyosmani/es6-tools)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following if you need regex:

```
var matcher = new RegExp(shortString + "\$", "g");
var found = matcher.test(longString );
```

Comment: The `$` should need to be escaped. Also shouldnt need to globally check on a single line.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `regex` from `shortString` and test with `match`:

```
var longString = "this string is long but why";
var shortString = "but why";
// build regex and escape the `$` (end of line) metacharacter
var regex = new RegExp(shortString + "\$");
var answer = regex.test(longString);
// true
console.log(answer);
```

Hope this helps